# Symbol.dispose ??= Symbol('dispose') error in render.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, render

Facing error below while using render.com:

```
==\> Running 'node index.js'
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM  /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/disposable.js:19
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM  Symbol.dispose ??= Symbol('dispose');
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM                 ^^^
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM  
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM      at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM      at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM      at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM      at Function.Module.\_load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM      at Object.\<anonymous\> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:23:25)
Oct 8 07:57:38 PM      at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
```

My index.js code is :

```
const express = require("express");
const {sl} = require("./sl");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.get("/scrape", (req, res) => {
    sl(res);
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Render Puppeteer server is up and running!");
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
 })
```

My scrapeLoading code is :

```
const express = require("express");
const {sl} = require("./sl");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.get("/scrape", (req, res) => {
    sl(res);
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Render Puppeteer server is up and running!");
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
 })
```

Also, I have already updated puppeteer and node.js

Comment: how are you building? what version of typescript? what version of node?

Comment: Your Node is probably out of date. Please double check what you updated Node to.

Comment: For setting the node version on render: https://render.com/docs/node-version

Answer (score 6):

Symbol.dispose ??= Symbol('dispose');
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

I encountered an error while using Puppeteer for PDF downloading in my Node.js web application. It appeared to be a syntax error, and I spent a lot of time looking through my code to identify the problem. Eventually, I discovered that the issue was related to my "Node.js version not being up-to-date". Puppeteer did not support the version I was using. Once I updated my Node.js and Puppeteer, the issue was resolved.